# Qt - Error in compiling source for windows

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, sqlcipher

I'm trying to compile qt with `sqlcipher`.

But I am getting an error in the command `make` .

make Error:
[image]

Anyone have any idea how to solve the error?

Comment: Please use text for the error message, not screenshot. It is simple to copy/paste text out of the console.

Comment: Do you have OpenSSL on your PC? Please, show your configure string and PATH variable

Comment: Here is similar problem: https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/27754 . It points on missing `zlib` library.

Comment: zlib installed `zlib1.dll /mingw/bin - zconf.h zlib.h /mingw/include - libz.a libz.dll.a /mingw/lib`. But still with same error. Any idea how to resolve the error?

Comment: @Guinness Hello, PATH C:\OpenSSL-Win32; C:\MinGW

Comment: @user628298 can you show your "configure string"?

Comment: @Guinness "configure string" what would it be? fstab of mingw?

Comment: @user628298 it`s how you configure Qt before build it. For example,
configure -static -debug-and-release -opensource -opengl desktop -platform win32-g++

Comment: @Guinness Hello, the zlib error,  resolved. `./configure -platform   win32-g++`
But I got another problem, now it reports the `make` when accessing `/ src / widgets / widgets.pro` a window of `uic.exe alert` appears and informs `Qt5Core.dll not found`

Comment: @Guinness Added the `qt lib` in `mingw/bin`. Success in compile:) Thank you very much for your attention and help. :)